# stuck at 'must declare scalar variable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I already declare parameter in my query but when I executed it, there is an error

> Must declare scalar variable

What should I do?

```
 USE IMS_LOCATION

 SELECT TOP(100000)
     COALESCE(a.LOT_ID, b.LOT_ID, c.LOT_ID, d.LOT_ID) AS LotId, 
     COALESCE(a.CheckIn, b.CheckIn, c.CheckIn, d.CheckIn) AS CheckIn,
     COALESCE(a.CheckOut, b.CheckOut, c.CheckOut, d.CheckOut) AS CheckOut,
     COALESCE(a.StatusDesc, b.StatusDesc, c.StatusDesc, d.StatusDesc) AS 
 StatusDesc
 FROM
     LOT_LOC_BOND a
 LEFT JOIN 
     LOT_LOC_IEBT b ON a.LOT_ID = b.LOT_ID AND a.LOT_ID = @lotId,
     LOT_LOC_MBT c 
 LEFT JOIN 
     LOT_LOC_SEAL d ON c.LOT_ID = d.LOT_ID
```

Comment: where is declaration of `@lotId `?

Comment: if parameter is a number/decimal type you need to convert them to character first using `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Comment: What is the `,` at the end of the JOIN conditions for `LOT_LOC_TEBT` supposed to be?? What is the `LOT_LOC_MBT c` supposed to mean?? If you want to join that table too - use a **proper ANSI JOIN** like `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - not just a comma .....

Comment: @marc_s - You missed to mention `CROSS JOIN` that's what happening there

Comment: A clean-code advice. Always prefer to have filter conditions in where clause.  E.g. putting the condition `a.LOT_ID = @lotId` in `ON` clause will be hard to find for any coder who will maintain your code even though from performance stand-point it makes no difference for SQL Query engine.

Comment: @RBT - Wrong suggestion!!.. If you move it to `Where` clause it will work differently, I will agree if it is used in `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Pரதீப் ahaa. That's a left outer join. A gotcha for me. Can even the final result set differ in case of left outer join depending on the placement of filter conditions i.e. either in `where` clause or `ON` clause?

Comment: @RBT - Yes it will differ try it out..

Comment: @RBT Consider that if it didn't matter, you could write `a LEFT JOIN b ON 1=1 WHERE a.some_id = b.some_id`. This one will fail in almost every situation where you'd use a left join, so you can experiment on your own database.

Comment: Pரதீப் I already used inner join but the data is empty .

Comment: I think there is a typo in your query, and I don't think you want `@lotId` at all. My point here is: You are using `coalesce()` on the Lot IDs from four different tables, so you really don't know if `a.LotId` is `NULL` or not, right? So, why would you want to compare `a.LotId` (possibly `NULL`) with an external parameter?

Comment: @Peter Abolins I am also confused with myself. yeah i need to combine Lot Id's from different table and set it as a column so did the other column checkin,checkout and statusdesc. without coelesce I can't combine it all. it'll shows error. but when I am using coalesce it works. and right now I'm doing a system tht can filter this lotid  to display the result. and i need my lotid as a parameter, lotid value will be enter in a textbox. the result is going to be in other page. sorry for the long explaination cuz I'm super confused right now

Comment: @Joojoo Just to add to your confusion, the first part of the query is essentially telling you nothing at all. Sure, you may end up with a LotID, CheckIn, CheckOut and StatusDesc, but you won't know which tables these values come from, or indeed if they all come from the same one.

Take a break, figure out what it is you want to show, and then go back and figure out how to get it from the DB.

Comment: @PeterAbolins if you were in my shoes, what will you do to combine those lotid from different table into a column? so did the other column too. what will you do?

Comment: @Joojoo Ok... let's assume that the data in table A belongs together, and the same for table B, C and D. Therefore, you can't combine A.LotID with B.CheckIn, D.CheckOut and C.StatusDesc... Right? This assumes that a LotID in table A will not appear in table B as well?
If I am on the right track (lots of hypothetical work being done ;)) then you can use a set of `UNION` statements to select from tables A, B, C and D, and then filter (`WHERE`) by the LotID parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment above sort of indicates the following solution to your problem.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getLotInfo(@suppliedLotId INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
( 
    SELECT 
        combinedLotId, 
        combinedCheckIn, 
        combinedCheckOut, 
        combinedStatusDesc, 
        originTable 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            LOT_ID AS combinedLotId, 
            CheckIn AS combinedCheckIn, 
            CheckOut AS combinedCheckOut, 
            StatusDesc AS combinedStatusDesc, 
            'LOT_LOC_BOND' AS originTable
        FROM LOT_LOC_BOND 
        UNION SELECT 
            LOT_ID, CheckIn, CheckOut, StatusDesc, 'LOT_LOC_IEBT'
        FROM LOT_LOC_IEBT 
        UNION SELECT 
            LOT_ID, CheckIn, CheckOut, StatusDesc, 'LOT_LOC_MBT'
        FROM LOT_LOC_MBT 
        UNION SELECT 
            LOT_ID, CheckIn, CheckOut, StatusDesc, 'LOT_LOC_SEAL'
        FROM LOT_LOC_SEAL 
    ) AS results
    WHERE combinedLotId = @suppliedLotId
);
```

The function may not fit your needs perfectly, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: The table names are a, b, c, d for brevity. Feel free to replace them with the actual table names (LOT_LOC_BOND, LOT_LOC_IEBT, LOT_LOC_MBT and LOT_LOC_SEAL).

Comment: thankyou so much for your help, I am definitely will try this query but what is origintable supposed to be? i can not understand

Comment: @Joojoo I added originTable so that you can see which of the four unioned tables the data comes from. I have no idea whether this is useful to you, but from my point of view, it made sense.

Instead of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', originTable would have a value of 'LOT_LOC_BOND', 'LOT_LOC_IEBT', 'LOT_LOC_MBT' or 'LOT_LOC_SEAL', depending on which table the information was found in.

Comment: @Joojoo I have updated my answer to reflect the actual table names, rather than the generic names (a, b, c and d).